# Polymer: missing dependencies

Tags: dependencies, polymer, polymer-elements

I just created a polymer element. What I don't understand is that when I use it in an application, it's dependencies (other polymer elements) are missing.

The head of my file:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link ref="import" href="../paper-styles/color.html">
<link ref="import" href="../polymer-keydown/polymer-keydown.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-a11y-keys/iron-a11y-keys.html">
```

My `bower.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-el",
  "description": "a description",
  "main": "my-el.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.4.0",
    "iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#^1.1.3",
    "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#^1.0.10",
    "iron-a11y-keys": "PolymerElements/iron-a11y-keys#^1.0.6",
    "polymer-keydown": "dmytroyarmak/polymer-keydown#^0.1.0",
    "paper-styles": "PolymerElements/paper-styles#^1.1.4"
  }
}
```

When running a simple example, only parts of the dependencies are loaded. Here is the components folder as it appears under the source tab in the developer console:

```
components
├── iron-a11y-keys
├── iron-a11y-keys-behavior
├── iron-flex-layout
├── iron-icon
├── iron-icons
├── iron-iconset-svg
├── iron-meta
├── my-el
├── polymer
├── webcomponentsjs
```

It tried to launch the app with `polymer serve` and `polyserve`, same behavior.

Why `polymer-keydown` and `paper-styles` are missing ?

Comment: Are you not getting any 404s?

Comment: Not one, this is the weirdest part: the query is not even made.

Comment: Weird, I just tried the same bower and it works as it should. Ensure your connection, and make a `rm -rf bower_components && bower cache clean && bower install` to see if the problem persist